# Is there a difference between Superman’s Gotham City and Batman’s?

Tags: dc, batman, superman

Is there any difference between Batman's Gotham City and Superman's Gotham City?What happens if they make a movie in which both appear together? Which city will they show? E.g. in Justice League.

Comment: Batman lives in Gotham, Superman lives in Metropolis. They both exist in the same Canon universe.

Comment: The basic lack of information in this question requires me to refer the asker to reading more closely before being stumped by the obvious setting or context of a character. This sort of question tests one's patience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Superman doesn't live in Gotham City.

Superman lives in Metropolis. It seems to be relatively near Gotham geographically (both appear to be in something like the New England area), but they're *definitely* different cities.

In fact, there's often tension when one hero works in the other hero's city, and that is likely to be a factor in any meeting they have. It's certainly been a regular point of contention in previous teamups, especially when it's just about the two of them and not about the whole Justice League.

Some visual representations may have the cities look similar, but generally Gotham is more brooding and gargoyle-infested, with a stoney Art Deco style (at least since the 1980s *Batman* film and subsequent Animated Series codified that look), while Metropolis has sleeker lines and is more "modern" with glass and steel (to reflect the "Man of Tomorrow" theme) rather than Gotham's ornate stone buildings carved with humanoid figures.

Comment: I just said that. ..

Comment: @Richard As a comment? That's not what comments are for.

Comment: I meant that the whole premise of the question seems flawed ;-)

Comment: @Richard I think [a principle of the site is that we don't expect questioners to be familiar with the material they ask about](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2372/13941), and we regularly field questions based on fundamental misunderstandings of the material. You didn't vote to close or suggest a way to improve the question, so it looked like a "comment answer" to me, and I ignore comment answers. In the future try to be more explicit about what the purpose of your comment is, and this might not happen again.

Comment: My joke had fallen on deaf ears... ;-(

Comment: I don't know how much it lines up with the comics, but in Smallville (the show), Metropolis seemed to be within driving distance of Smallville, Kansas.

Comment: @phantom42 Smallville should be considered its own closed continuity, aligned with nothing outside itself and only vaguely resembling other DC properties.

Comment: @BESW, thanks. I was unsure since some of my friends who are strict-canonicty freaks still really loved the show. Does it not fit in with the other DC live shows either?

Comment: @phantom42 DC live show intercanonicity is probably worth asking as its own proper question on the site!